# Assign a specific location to tikzpicture in beamer slide?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to define a format for slides, which contain both text and graphics, in my presentation such that each slide has some FIXED part for graphics and text. The two portions of slide does not need to be equal.

I have two questions

1. Is it possible to pre-allocate a part of beamer slide, either vertical or horizontal, for a graphic created using tikz package.
2. Within the graphic part, the size of picture is adjusted according to the available space

Comment: As others have noted on other questions of yours: Beamer has special overlay specifications to uncover parts of slides bit-by-bit. These work with parts of `tikzpicture`s just as they do with other slide content. I suspect it'd be better to use these than try to redraw and align all the parts.

Comment: I think what OP wants is a slide format (like powerpoints slide master) where there is one image and one text box. @NAASI have you tried `\begin{columns}` to create two columns side by side?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Beamer allows us to allocate `N` number of columns **side by side**. See Beamer manual scetion `12.7 Splitting a Frame into Multiple Columns`. From the manual:

```
The beamer class offers several commands and
environments for splitting (perhaps only part of)
a frame into multiple columns.
***some text removed***
Columns are especially useful for placing a graphic
next to a description/explanation.
```

Here is a sample (modified after @Zarko comment below)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth} %width of the column
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Figure caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    Some long series of text or images or anything really.
    Writing here restricts it to right half of this slide.
    Some long series of text or images or anything really.
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: more correct is `\begin{columns}[t]\begin{column}{\0.5\textwidth} ...\end{column}\begin{column}...\end{column}\end{columns}`. Also options for placing of figures is surplus, since `beamer` doesn't use them.

Comment: Is the `\column` command less preferred with respect to the `\begin{column}` version? The figure command was copy pasted :D

Comment: As far as I see, columns as well column is an environment, not a command. Environments always have a form `\begin{...} ... \end{...}`. For columns see description in section "12.7 Splitting a Frame into Multiple Columns", page 125 in Beamer manual (v 3.36).

Comment: I went thorough the section 12.7(v3.36) once more. The documentation doesn't seem to favor either one. I have modified the example above to use the `\begin ... \end` version.